# Making a Callback for AJAX Requests to return the response to the caller

Tags: javascript, ajax, callback

I've looked all over the place and none of the answers I've found have been able to help me out with this problem. Basically I have a function that calls a separate function to make an `XMLHttpRequest`. The request goes to a server, which generates a random number and returns it to the page.

The problem is that while the request is fetching the data, the caller function continues through its commands. I need to have the data from the request before the caller can move forward. People have mentioned callbacks and promises, neither of which I have been able to grasp with what's available online. I'd rather use callbacks because promises aren't supported in all browsers. Can someone please help walk me through how to use them? I can provide some of the code that I have if needed.

Here's my caller function:

```
function plotData(dataSet) 
{   
var x = xScale+20; // 20 = margin length
var y = 260;    //origin of graph

getRequest();
console.log("x = "+x);  
console.log("dataSet = "+dataSet[0]+", "+dataSet[1]); 
... //rest of the function commands
}
```

Here's my XML Request:

```
function getRequest()
{
var request;

if (window.XMLHttpRequest) 
{ // Mozilla, Safari, IE7+ ...
    request = new XMLHttpRequest();
} 
else if (window.ActiveXObject) 
{ // IE 6 and older
    request = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}   
    request.onreadystatechange = function()
    {   
        console.log('onReady');
        if (request.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE)
        {
            if (request.status === 200)
            {
                random = request.responseText;
                random = parseInt(random);
                random = random/100;
                random = random.toFixed(2);
                console.log("random = " +random);
                data[1] = random;
                console.log("data = "+data[0]+", "+data[1]);
            }
        else
        {
            alert ('There was a problem with the request');
        }

        }
}   
request.open("GET", "lak1010_hw05.php", true);
request.send();     
}
```

Comment: You have to use callback. Can you post the code you tried and I can tell you then regarding the callback?

Comment: @Aruna just added it

Comment: Can you post the `getRequest` function code and I will fix it up as it seems very straight forward here.

Comment: @Aruna Posted the whole function

Comment: I have posted the modified code and please give a try.

Comment: `getRequest` is now passing a callback function. You should move the last two lines of `plotData` function inside the callback function and change them accordingly.

Comment: Just figured that out 1 second before you posted. Thanks this helps so much!

Comment: Great, you are welcome :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your modified `getRequest` function with the callback,

```
function getRequest(callback)
{
var request;

if (window.XMLHttpRequest) 
{ // Mozilla, Safari, IE7+ ...
    request = new XMLHttpRequest();
} 
else if (window.ActiveXObject) 
{ // IE 6 and older
    request = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}   
    request.onreadystatechange = function()
    {   
        console.log('onReady');
        if (request.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE)
        {
            if (request.status === 200)
            {
                random = request.responseText;
                random = parseInt(random);
                random = random/100;
                random = random.toFixed(2);
                console.log("random = " +random);
                data[1] = random;
                console.log("data = "+data[0]+", "+data[1]);
                // here call your callback
                callback(random);
            }
        else
        {
            alert ('There was a problem with the request');
        }

        }
}   
request.open("GET", "lak1010_hw05.php", true);
request.send();     
}
```

Your calling method,

```
function plotData(dataSet) 
{   
var x = xScale+20; // 20 = margin length
var y = 260;    //origin of graph

getRequest(function(random){
   console.log('Random number received:');
   console.log(random);
});
console.log("x = "+x);  
console.log("dataSet = "+dataSet[0]+", "+dataSet[1]); 
... //rest of the function commands
}
```

Comment: I was thinking about this last night before I went to bed. The code worked, but I have no idea why or how. Can you try to explain what's going on here? Why can the `callback` function work if it was never defined? And what exactly is happening in the `getRequest` call in `plotData`?

Comment: When you are calling `getRequest` function from `plotData`, you are passing a whole function `function(random){ ... }` as argument named `callback` to the function implementation of `getRequest`. Once the ajax response is got inside the `getRequest` function then the same function referenced as argument `callback` is invoked as `callback(random)`. So the code inside the supplied function is getting executed. That's it! Read this again and again until you understand this or search google for the term callback to get more understanding.

Comment: So `callback` is actually defined within `plotData`, `getRequest` executes this function within itself, finishes, and then proceeds with the caller. Does `callback` have to be at the end of the `getRequest` commands?

Comment: Yes you are right. As you said `callback` is defined in the caller and the way to return back to the caller from `getRequest` once the asynchronous (ajax) operation ends. That's why its called as `call back`. `callback` function is defined as argument in `plotData` when calling `getRequest` and you can invoke this inside `getRequest` function whenever you need to do/send something to the caller (`plotData`) like end of ajax response etc.

Answer (score 1):

Promises are the way to go here.  You can use a Promise polyfill to help take care of unsupported browsers.

```
var myPromise = (function() {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        $.ajax({
            url:'/page.php?id=123',
            type:'POST',
            success: function(data) {
                resolve(data);
            }
        });
    });
})();
myPromise.then(function(data) {
  // Continue code here
});
```

Basically you create a promise that gets resolved with the data returned from your AJAX call.  `myPromise.then()` gets fired when the Promise is resolved and you continue your code execution there with the data you passed along in the promise resolution.  You can also `reject()` a promise if the AJAX error'd or had invalid data etc.

With your code something like this:

```
function plotData(dataSet) 
{   
var x = xScale+20; // 20 = margin length
var y = 260;    //origin of graph
var myPromise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    $.ajax({
        url:'/page.php?id=123',
        type:'POST',
        success: function(dataSet) {
            resolve(dataSet);
        }
    });
});

myPromise.then(function(dataSet) {
    console.log("x = "+x);  
    console.log("dataSet = "+dataSet[0]+", "+dataSet[1]); 
    ... //rest of the function commands
});


}
```

Simpler with just the callback:

```
function plotData(dataSet) 
{   
var x = xScale+20; // 20 = margin length
var y = 260;    //origin of graph

    $.ajax({
        url:'/page.php?id=123',
        type:'POST',
        success: function(dataSet) {
            console.log("x = "+x);  
            console.log("dataSet = "+dataSet[0]+", "+dataSet[1]); 
            ... //rest of the function commands
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: This is similar to a lot of the stuff I found online, could you try to put it in context for the code I've provided? (Not asking you to write my program for me, I just get confused at the vague function names.)

Comment: I found an answer but I appreciate you helping with promises. I'll look into them more and hopefully get a better grasp on them. Do you need to use jQuery for them?

Comment: No jquery isn't required was just using it for the brevity of showing an Ajax request

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: Well shit I missed your edit and thought it was just a general promise question.

This is a function with parameters:

```js
test = function(parameter) {
  if (paramater) {
    return true
  } else {
    return false
  }
}
```

This is a function that has an extra parameter called a 'callback'.

```js
test = function(parameter, callback) {
  if (parameter) {
    callback(null, 'result')
  } else {
    callback('error')
  }
}
```

A callback usually has two arguments. An error, and an optional result.

As you can see, if parameter is true, we run a function that returns 'null' as the error, and 'result' as the result.

If you'd like to delay functions using a callback, you simply call the function like this:

```js
test(true, function(err, result) {
  if(err) {
    console.log(err)
  } else {
    console.log(result)
  }
})
```

Replace console.log with the function you want upon a successful result or error. It's hard to understand at first, but try writing some code for it - the reading is usually useless when you don't have an ingrained idea of asynchronous code.

You have to manually add the callbacks and stuff - here's an extract from my backend.

```js
this.findOneByPhone = function(phone, req, res, callback) {
        connection.acquire(function(err, con) {
            con.query('select * from users where phone = ?', [phone], function(err, result) {
                con.release()
                if (err) {
                    callback(err)
                } else {
                    callback(null, JSON.stringify(result[0], null, 4))
                }
            })
        })
    }
```

And then calling it;

```js
this.findOneByPhone(user.phone, null, null, function(err, foundUser) {
                if (err) {
                    res.status(500).json({message: 'Signup findOneByPhone failed.', error: err})
                } else {
                    if (foundUser) {
                        var foundUserJSON = JSON.parse(foundUser)
                        res.json({status: 0, message: 'User already found in database, please skip signup', result: 'skip'})
                    } else {
                        res.json({status: 0, message: 'User is not in database, please signup', result: 'signup'})
                    }
                }
            })
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the new fetch API. Promises with jQuery are pretty broken :/

=> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch

```
    var myHeaders = new Headers();

    var myInit = { method: 'GET',
                   headers: myHeaders,
                   mode: 'cors',
                   cache: 'default' };

    fetch('flowers.jpg', myInit)
    .then(function(response) {
      return response.blob();
    })
    .then(function(myBlob) {
      var objectURL = URL.createObjectURL(myBlob);
      myImage.src = objectURL;
    });
```