# How to wait until a whole loop of AJAX request finishes to execute next block of code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asynchronous

My objective is to get data from API using `$.ajax` call, push each successful data into arrays, and after getting all data (all ajax stops), I append them to the html page.
While the code below here has satisfied my goal by using `$(document).ajaxStop()`, I want to ask if there is any different way to wait until all ajax finishes in a loop from i to n times? The point is in the future, maybe I only need all ajax in the loop stops/finishes to get some data, do something with it, then call some ajax after that, but not when all ajax in my whole script stops? (the use of `ajaxStop()` to me may not be useful at all times).

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var streamList = ["HSdogdog", "AdmiralBulldog", "vanNDota", "DreamLeague", "WubWoofWolf", "17uu", "lamperkat", "febbydoto", "Arteezy", "AmazHS", "Moonmeander", "WagamamaTV", "dotademon", "feardota", "esl_dota2", "monkeys_forever", "Dendi", "sheevergaming", "BigDaddy", "Draskyl", "Chessie", "FollowAkke", "bOne7", "attackerdota", "noobfromua", "egm", "qojqva", "alohadancetv", "pajkattdota", "dotastarladder_en", "barnyyy", "zai", "aui_2000", "universedota", "ppd", "fogged", "purgegamers", "meraclechamlotte", "7ckngmad", "miracle_doto", "puppey", "h4nn1", "420jenkins", "illidanstrdoto", "sumaildoto", "jeraxai", "grandgrant", "jeyodude", "bananaslamjamma", "yawar_", "merlinidota", "beyondthesummit", "s4", "stormspirittv", "synderen", "funn1k", "emperorpenguin83", "kano", "miserytheslayer", "reimudesu", "shigetora", "matumbaman", "era17", "sneykingdota", "siractionslacks", "moodota2", "dizzykitten", "sakurafrost225", "Rafis0", "odpixel", "d47biryu", "vampyrette", "w33haa", "blitzdota", "ritsugamer", "limmp", "himegurecia", "dotamajor", "babyknight", "ccncdota2", "lil_hardy", "angelsimosu", "vankhoahoang", "resolut1ontv", "blackdotatv", "sing_sing", "midone", "eternalenvyy", "dotacapitalist", "keemerah", "osu_HDHR", "mssdota", "epicenter_en1", "koushudota", "yapzordota", "moonducktv", "pikachama", "qSnake_", "stan_king", "dota2fata", "madaradota2", "braxton911", "cr1tdota", "mikah138", "evilgeniuses", "dotagasm", "official_niqua", "arise_3012", "nooneboss", "forev", "ramzesdoto", "aliastar", "bububu", "0timado0", "envybaer", "smashdota", "nurbika", "brinkdota", "canceldota", "qodota2", "day9tv", "zingle313", "kvhdota", "abed_dota", "ohaiyodota", "boris_dota", "gorgcc", "ltt98", "pgl_dota", "spare", "hfndota", "happystick", "itshafu", "thijshs", "qsnake", "lizzarddota2", "ek0p", "godot", "chainsito11", "freecodecamp", "aepicenter_en2", "Clarkeezy", "NoctisAK47", "Solitary_Judge"];
  var online = [];
  var offline = [];
  var k = 0;
  var promise = [];
  var promise2 = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < streamList.length; i++) {
    var request = $.ajax({
      url: "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/" + streamList[i] + "?client_id=rznf9ecq10bbcwe91n6hhnul3dbpg9",
      dataType: 'json'
    });
    promise.push(request);
    request.done(function(data) {
      if (data.stream !== null) {
        online[k++] = {
          channel: data.stream.channel.display_name,
          game: data.stream.game,
          title: data.stream.channel.status,
          viewer: data.stream.viewers,
          icon: data.stream.channel.logo
        };
      } else if (data.stream === null) {
        var request2 = $.ajax({
          url: "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/" + streamList[i] + "?client_id=rznf9ecq10bbcwe91n6hhnul3dbpg9",
          dataType: 'json'
        });
        promise2.push(request2);
        request2.done(function(data2) {
          offline.push({
            channel: data2.display_name,
            game: data2.game,
            title: data2.status,
            viewer: "Offline",
            icon: data2.logo
          });
        });
      }
    });
  }

  $.when.apply($, promise).then(function() {
    $.when.apply($, promise2).then(function() {
      console.log("this is the final line of console.log");
      $("table").addClass("animated fadeIn");
      $(".loading").detach();
      online.sort(function(a, b) {
        if (a.viewer > b.viewer) {
          return -1;
        } else if (a.viewer < b.viewer) {
          return 1;
        }
        return 0;
      });

      $("thead").append("<tr><th style='width:25%' class = 'channel'>Channel</th><th class = 'game' style = 'width:20%'>Game</th><th>Title</th><th style = 'width: 15%'>Viewers</th></tr>");

      for (var i = 0; i < online.length; i++) {
        if (online[i].icon !== null) {
          $(".table").append("<tr><td class='name'><img class ='icon' src ='" + online[i].icon + "'>" + online[i].channel + "</td><td>" + online[i].game + "</td><td>" + online[i].title + "</td><td><span id='red'></span> " + online[i].viewer + "</td></tr>");
        } else if (online[i].icon === null) {
          $(".table").append("<tr><td class='name'><img class ='icon' src='https://i.imgur.com/0C7WUis.png'>" + online[i].channel + "</td><td>" + online[i].game + "</td><td>" + online[i].title + "</td><td><span id='red'></span> " + online[i].viewer + "</td></tr>");
        }
      }

      for (var j = 0; j < offline.length; j++) {
        if (offline[j].icon !== null) {
          $(".table").append("<tr><td class='name' style='color:#B2ADBF'><img class ='icon-offline' src ='" + offline[j].icon + "'>" + offline[j].channel + "</td><td style='color:#B2ADBF'><em>" + offline[j].game + "</em></td><td style='color:#B2ADBF'>" + offline[j].title + "</td><td style='color:#B2ADBF'>" + offline[j].viewer + "</td></tr>");
        } else if (offline[j].icon === null) {
          $(".table").append("<tr><td class='name' style='color:#B2ADBF'><img class ='icon-offline' src='https://i.imgur.com/0C7WUis.png'>" + offline[j].channel + "</td><td style='color:#B2ADBF'><em>" + offline[j].game + "</em></td><td style='color:#B2ADBF'>" + offline[j].title + "</td><td style='color:#B2ADBF'>" + offline[j].viewer + "</td></tr>");
        }
      }

      $("tbody tr").click(function() {
        window.open("https://www.twitch.tv/" + $(this).find('td.name').text());
      });
    });
  });


});
```

**EDIT 1:** After browsing through many topics related to $.when([passing array of deferreds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5627284/pass-in-an-array-of-deferreds-to-when)) and also how to deal with [nested AJAX calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8097516/how-to-wait-until-nested-async-jquery-ajax-requests-have-finished), I have finally achieved what I want (I edited my snippet code, basically using a nested $.when and you pass array of promises inside). However, a new problem arises, my code works super well only if all promises resolved (all AJAX call returns data succesfully). In the case of a failed AJAX call, i.e. data not found after AJAX call returns, the inner promises array will not resolve, hence never append the data into HTML page. So I have tried changing `$.when.apply($, promise2).then(function())` to `$.when.apply($, promise2).always(function()`, however, the `always` doesn't seem to work as I want since as soon as a AJAX calls return error, it will append the data to my HTML page, hence missing data will be requested after appending is done, so the `console.log("This is the final line ...")` that I have tried as an indicator doesn't appear at the final line anymore. Am I missing something with `.always().` since it does not wait for `$.when()` to ensure all promises have been either rejected or resolved, rather it runs when any promises got rejected.

**EDIT 2**: I have finally solved my problem if anyone is still interested. The `$.always()` that I misunderstood above was actually working as intended, if any promises got rejected, it will execute the function after `$.always()` nonetheless even if there are still more promises pending in the array. So thanks to this [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6538470/jquery-deferred-waiting-for-multiple-ajax-requests-to-finish/13627555#13627555), what I did is basically map all promises of promise2 array (array that will have failed promises) to resolve state whenever it is called. This is the snippet:

```
promise2 = $.map(promise2, function (p) {          
       var dfd = $.Deferred();
       p.always(function () {
          dfd.resolve();
       });
       return dfd.promise();
}
```

Comment: Wrap the loop into a function and make it return a [**deferred promise**](https://api.jquery.com/deferred.promise/)

Comment: I'm not actually getting this promise thingy, especially the resolve and reject one. Can you be more detailed? Thank you.

Comment: See http://learn.jquery.com/code-organization/deferreds/ for more information about deferreds/promises.

Comment: I asked a similar question before and got a good answer. Check it out here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43082016/making-a-callback-for-ajax-requests-to-return-the-response-to-the-caller

Comment: Take a look at nsynjs, it is not based on promises and can run mix of api calls and logic in sequential manner. Here is an example that is similar to yours: https://github.com/amaksr/nsynjs/blob/master/examples/browser-ajax-seq.js

Comment: What I understood from the deferred promise that I've read for the last 30 mins is that you create a deferred variable, create a resolve state, do a $.when(function).then(another_function), the another_function will append to my html only when the function is resolved. But how do i create a resolve after all ajax finishes in my function with loops, since it's async so it will execute the resolve state even before the data has been fetched completely.

Comment: I don't think you understood how `$.when` works. Have a look at [its documentation](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/). You pass *n* promises to `$.when`, not a function. The callback will only be called after all the promises have resoled. E.g. `$.when(promise1, promise2, ...).then(runAfterAllResolved)`. You can also [call `$.when` with an array of promises](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5627284/218196).

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have tried doing that and it seemed to progress. However, my $.when only waits until all first ajax call finishes, not the nested ajax if the data is null. I will try to work on that somehow.